# Http client in angular

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous, subscribe

I have problem with understanding of async angular http client. I had backend part written in Java where endpoints return data with the same format but different meaning. So I decided to create follow code:

```
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  temperatureDailyCharts: Chart[] = new Array();

  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getDailyParameterCharts("temperature", this.temperatureDailyCharts);

  }

  getDailyParameterCharts(parameter: string, chartList: Chart[]) {
    this.weatherService.getDailyParameter(1, parameter)
      .subscribe(response => chartList = response);
  }
}
```

Next step  is injecting `this.temperatureDailyCharts[0]` to child component, and waiting for `ngOnChange`. This code doesn't work correctly, because `ngOnChanges` method will never invoke. If I change my subscribe part to explicity sign value

```
.subscribe(response => this.temperatureDailyCharts = response);
```

it is ok. Please, explain me why this (from my point of view both codes are the same) construction is bad?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript by reference vs. by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value)

Comment: JavaScript passes arguments by value, just like Java. Assigning a new value to chartList will modify the value of the **local variable** chartList, not the value of this.temperatureDailyCharts, just as in Java. This has nothing to do with HTTP. Just with how JavaScript arguments are passed to functions.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript passes function arguments by *value* . In case of objects, we have object references (memory addresses) which are copied by value. In this case `this.temperatureDailyCharts` is a reference to an object, this reference gets copied into the activation record of the `getDailyParameterCharts()` function. In the assignments, you override (re-assign) this copied reference - which of course doesn't have effect on the original reference (which is a local value in `ngOnInit()`).

Edit: sometimes "passing a reference by value" is also called "passing by reference". You can read more here: https://codeburst.io/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c